# Communicate back with Parent Window

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, user-controls

My WPF application has a UserControl which does stuff.

My Parent Window has a ListBox.

My question is how can I access the ListBox while I am in the UserControl?

Comment: I dont know what MVVMLight is. I am using Code Behind

Comment: what are you trying to access in the listbox?

Comment: the list box would be bound to a ObservableCollection<YourType> and so would the UserControl. so they are both acting on the same data but not with eachother

Comment: @CJK My UserControl processes a file. I want to post messages to the ListBox that would be like status.Add("File opened") and the MainWindow->ListBox would display it. For some reason I can not access the ListBox in MainWindow. I can only access it if I move the ListBox into my UserControl

Comment: Ok, I've suggested an edit that adds that information to your question for anyone else looking at it to have a better idea of what you want to do.

Comment: What I generally do in this case is have the 2nd viewmodel have private parent property that is of type MainViewmodel. When you construct a 2nd VM assuming from the MainViewModel, just pass the constructor this.  then you can access _parent.property

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this in your user control:

`Window yourParentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);`

Then you should be able to access your ListBox through yourParentWindow.

Comment: I saw this before and tried it. yourParentWindow.listBoxStatusMessages doesn't show up. (my listbox is called listBoxStatusMessages)